# ADF dynamic content using concat - need to embed commas inside of string for long list of columns

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-adf

The use case seems pretty simple....
**Produce a sql statement as part of a copy activity that includes a hard coded column listing and also concatenated to a parameter-provided database and table name** (since the database and table names can change across environments such as dev/test/prod).

The problem is....**If you use concat function it treats every comma as a new value to be concatenated**.  I was hoping for a way to escape the comma and treat it as a value but nothing I've tried works.

For example....concatenate the following string ....
SELECT event_date, event_timestamp,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_title') AS page_title
FROM '
to... pipeline().parameters.Database_Nm + . + pipeline().parameters.Table_Nm

The workaround has been to quote the beginning and end of every line so the comma is treated as data so every column/line is a separate concatenation such as this....

@concat('SELECT event_date,',
'(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = ''page_title'') AS page_title,',
'from ', pipeline().parameters.Database_Nm, '.', pipeline().parameters.Table_Nm

That works...but I have over a hundred columns so this is just a bit silly as a solution. Am I missing a simpler method?  TIA!

Answer (score 1):

When most of your string is hard coded and not expressions you can use the following [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) expression format:

```
SELECT event_date,
 (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_title') AS page_title
from @{pipeline().parameters.Database_Nm}.@{pipeline().parameters.Table_Nm}
```

Comment: So there WAS something obvious I was missing, thank you!!!

Comment: In case there are others extracting from Bigquery  I've included the final solution below....

(Note below v_Extract_Dt is derived inside of ForEach loop using set variable activity and it's using 4 single quotes to wrap in single quotes: @concat('''', item().event_date, '''')

FROM
  @{variables('v_BigQuery_From_Stmt')},
  UNNEST (items) AS unnest_items
  WHERE event_date = @{variables('v_Extract_Dt')}